# ARKit CoachingOverlay in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, arkit

Using [Madison Gipson's implementation](https://blog.devgenius.io/implementing-ar-in-swiftui-without-storyboards-ec529ace7ab2) of ARSCNView in SwiftUI, and I'd like to add an ARKit CoachingOverlay to my ARView before it renders onto an anchor.

I've tried adding [this Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62388053/reset-arview-and-run-coaching-overlay-again) but it throws errors I don't know how to solve (see code).

I've also tried to take hints from [Apple's ARKit demo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/environmental_analysis/placing_objects_and_handling_3d_interaction) which implements CoachingOverlay, but without luck.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import ARKit

@main
struct Window: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ARViewContainer()
        }
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ARView {
        return ARView()
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ARView, context: Context) { }
    
}

class ARView: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {
    
    var arView: ARSCNView {
        return self.view as! ARSCNView
    }
    override func loadView() {
        self.view = ARSCNView(frame: .zero)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        arView.delegate = self
        arView.scene = SCNScene()
        setupCoachingOverlay() // <------------------------------- set up coaching overlay.
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        arView.session.run(configuration)
        arView.delegate = self
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        arView.session.pause()
    }
    func sessionWasInterrupted(_ session: ARSession) {}
    func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {}
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {}
    func session(_ session: ARSession, cameraDidChangeTrackingState
                    camera: ARCamera) {}
}

extension ARView: ARCoachingOverlayViewDelegate {
    
    func setupCoachingOverlay() {
        let coachingOverlay = ARCoachingOverlayView()
        coachingOverlay.delegate = self
        coachingOverlay.session = self.session // ERROR: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
        coachingOverlay.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        coachingOverlay.goal = .anyPlane
        self.addSubview(coachingOverlay) // ERROR: Value of type 'ARView' has no member 'addSubview'
    }
    
}
```

Comment: That's because `ARView` is a `ViewController`.  `ViewController` _is not_ a view, it _has_ a view. Maybe you meant `self.view.addSubview(coachingOverlay)`?