# Is it possible to use SwiftUI for UI in an AR-App using SceneKit?

Tags: swiftui, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I am currently working on an AR-App using SceneKit. I can't use RealityKit because I need Image Recognition which it doesn't support at this time.
With [this tutorial](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-use-a-swiftui-view-in-anarkit-scenekit-app-d6504d7b92d2) I found a way to integrate SwiftUI into the AR-Scene but not as a typical UI-/HUD-Element.

Is it there a way to use SceneKit for Image Recognition **and** SwiftUI as UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a certain way you can. Here's a Medium [story](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-use-a-swiftui-view-in-anarkit-scenekit-app-d6504d7b92d2) on this topic. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582392/swiftui-passing-data-from-swiftuiview-to-scenekit/60590065#60590065) SO post might be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. [This Tutorial](https://medium.com/dev-genius/implementing-ar-in-swiftui-without-storyboards-ec529ace7ab2) helped me accomplish my needs.