# RealityKit – Image recognition and working with many scenes

Tags: swift, swiftui, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I've created an app using the RealityKit template file. Inside RealityComposer there are multiple scenes, all the scenes use image recognition that activates some animations.

Inside Xcode I have to load all the scenes as anchors and append those anchors to `arView.scene.anchors` array. The issue is an obvious one, as I present the physical 2D image one after the other I get multiple anchors piled on top of each other which is not desirable. I'm aware of `arView.scene.anchors.removeAll()` prior to loading the new anchor but my issue is this:

How do I check when a certain image has appeared to therefore remove the existing anchor and load the correct one? I've tried to look for something like there is in ARKit as `didUpdate` but I can't see anything similar in RealityKit.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Foreword***

RealityKit's `AnchorEntity(.image)` coming from RC, matches ARKit's [ARImageTrackingConfig](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arimagetrackingconfiguration). When iOS device recognises a reference image, it creates Image Anchor (that conforms to `ARTrackable` protocol) that tethers a corresponding 3D model. And, as you understand, you must show just one reference image at a time (in your particular case AR app can't operate normally when you give it two or more images simultaneously).

Code snippet showing how `if condition` logic might look like:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {            
        return ARViewContainer().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {    
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

        let id02Scene = try! Experience.loadID2()            
        print(id02Scene)     // prints scene hierarchy
        
        let anchor = id02Scene.children[0]
        print(anchor.components[AnchoringComponent] as Any)
        
        if anchor.components[AnchoringComponent] == AnchoringComponent(
                      .image(group: "Experience.reality", 
                              name: "assets/MainID_4b51de84.jpeg")) {
            
            arView.scene.anchors.removeAll()
            print("LOAD SCENE")
            arView.scene.anchors.append(id02Scene)
        }
        return arView
    }
 
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

`ID2` scene hierarchy printed in console:

[image]

P.S.

You should implement SwiftUI `Coordinator` class (read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582392/swiftui-passing-data-from-swiftuiview-to-scenekit/60590065?)), and inside Coordinator use ARSessionDelegate's [session(_:didUpdate:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate/2865611-session) instance method to update anchors properties at 60 fps.

Also you may use the following logic – if anchor of scene 1 is active or anchor of scene 3 is active, just delete all anchors from collection and load scene 2.

```
var arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

let id01Scene = try! Experience.loadID1()
let id02Scene = try! Experience.loadID2()
let id03Scene = try! Experience.loadID3()

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {    
    arView.session.delegate = context.coordinator

    arView.scene.anchors.append(id01Scene)
    arView.scene.anchors.append(id02Scene)
    arView.scene.anchors.append(id03Scene)
    return arView
}
```

...

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    if arView.scene.anchors[0].isActive || arView.scene.anchors[2].isActive {
        arView.scene.anchors.removeAll()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(id02Scene)
        print("Load Scene Two")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that however Im getting this error "Cannot find 'anchorInRealityComposerScene' in scope". Im thinking that I should be placing my own custom name in there or else it is out of scope somehow.

Comment: `anchorInRealityComposerScene` is abstract name of your anchor in scene's hierarchy...

Comment: I see you are referring to anchors inside the Composer Scene but the only access to anchors that I can see is just using "arView.scene.anchors.components[AnchoringComponent]" which throws an error "AnchorCollection has no member 'components'"

Comment: If I am to use the reference from loading the Experience scene can I actually load all the scenes at once into one variable so that I can check that variable.components? All I have found online is to load scene by scene but I need a variable that references all the scenes at once dont I?

Comment: Of course I mean anchor entity from each scene inside `Experience.rcproject`.

Comment: Publish your code and share your scene via file sharing service (https://dropmefiles.com is OK) – and I'll try to help you. You gave a minimum information about your project.

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/zrcxY This is quite embarrassing as I was just hacking the template file in Xcode and its a real mess, see what you can do to help. Really appreciate it. jeremyraven@icloud.com

Comment: Yes but if I copy and paste the code inside makeUIView 7 times and change the names to match each scene in RealityComposer, will it load the correct scene at the right time when it recognises the corresponding image? Thanks

Comment: What tactics you choose for loading scenes is up to you. I just showed how you can get to a specific Image Anchor, which, when triggered, will load a needed 3D model. It's your app, and you are an AR app builder))

Comment: And one more comment – Your AR app can't operate normally if it'll simultaneously see two or more images for detection. Just single one at a time.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I guess Im not understanding how the mechanics work with image recognition as i want the image seen through the camera to determine which scene to load therefore which anchor to add to the arview.scene

Comment: Mechanics is simple: Event -> Anchor -> Model. If model learning algorithm (ML) recognises the reference image, it creates an ImageAnchor that tethers a 3D model.

Comment: If you wanna each time remove a previous model and load a new model, you definitely need to feed a camera with just one image at a time (in your particular case). That's all.

Comment: And remember two things – 1) Each ImageAnchor (RealityKit's AnchorEntity) is located in the very center of its corresponding reference image. 2) AnchorEntity(.image) matches ARKit's ARImageTrackingConfiguration (not ARWorldTrackingConfiguration) and it's very important...

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/sIC9U  Yes but the logic I am missing is in the following link. Only the last anchor8 is loaded even if the camera sees the other images one at a time. I see that removeall removes everything else but I just want the anchors to load when the right image appears.

Comment: Have you succeeded, Jeremy?

Comment: Almost there! :) I just have model anchors persisting after the reference image in the camera view disappears. So I get multiple entities on the screen at the same time. I think I need to use the updateUIView() method here?

Comment: 100% sure – you definitely need to update these anchors at 60 fps. IMHO you need SwiftUI `Coordinator` (like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582392/swiftui-passing-data-from-swiftuiview-to-scenekit/60590065?) but instead of `renderer(_:updateAtTime:)` use ARSessionDelegate's `session(_:didUpdate:)` instance method.