# How to change a folder of Reference Images?

Tags: swift, swiftui, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm trying to code with my iPad and the `Swift Playgrounds 4.0`. I tried to do Image Tracking with SwiftUI [example 1](https://github.com/riccqi/ARImageTracking) or [example 2](https://github.com/john-rocky/RealityKit-Sampler). It's possible to create a folder in the iPad App, but you can't put an Image in here... So the following code doesn't work:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {

    guard let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(
                                                  inGroupNamed: "AR Resources",
                                                        bundle: nil) 
    else {
        fatalError("Missing expected asset catalog resources.")
    }
}
```

[Here an Image from the Swift Playgrounds App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSK24.jpg)

Is it possible to use reference images from the root / main like you do with the `.usdz` models?

```
if let usdzModel = try? Entity.load(named: "drummer") {
    anchor.addChild(usdzModel)
}
```

Here is the complete Code:

```
import ARKit
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct RealityKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let view = ARView()
        
        // Start AR session
        let session = view.session
        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        config.planeDetection = [.horizontal]
        session.run(config)
        
        // Add coaching overlay
        let coachingOverlay = ARCoachingOverlayView()
        coachingOverlay.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        coachingOverlay.session = session
        coachingOverlay.goal = .horizontalPlane
        view.addSubview(coachingOverlay)
        
        // Set debug options
#if DEBUG
        view.debugOptions = [.showFeaturePoints, .showAnchorOrigins, .showAnchorGeometry]
#endif
        
        //AnchorEntity Bild
        
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(.image(group: "AR Resources", name: "Test"))
        // Create an image anchor by specifying the group name and image name of the AR resource
        let box = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: simd_make_float3(0.1, 0.03, 0.05)))
        anchor.addChild(box)
        
        view.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        
        //End AnchorEntity
        
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) {
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The [documentation for `ARReferenceImage` defines an initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arreferenceimage/2942252-init) you can use when you want to use an image that is not in the assets folder.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez thank you for the fast response! I'm new to Swift / AR development, I tried several things with `init(_ image: CGImage, 
orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation, 
physicalWidth: CGFloat)` but nothing works... (I think it was wrong?)

Answer (score 0):

It's a code snippet from my [Medium story](https://medium.com/@arkit/arkit-911-image-tracking-in-swift-playgrounds-702bc93f9fd1).

This is done differently from Xcode, but no more complicated than in Xcode. Use <kbd>+</kbd> button in the upper right corner of your Swift Playgrounds app to place your reference images there.

Then use this code.

```
import ARKit

let sceneView = ARSCNView(frame: .zero)
var trackingImages = Set<ARReferenceImage>()

fileprivate func feedSession() {
    
    let imageFromWeb = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Photo.png")
    
    let image = ARReferenceImage(imageFromWeb.cgImage!, orientation: .up, 
                                                      physicalWidth: 0.5)
    
    self.trackingImages.insert(image)
    
    let config = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()
    config.trackingImages = trackingImages
    self.sceneView.session.run(config)
}
```

Comment: I edited the complete Code of my Swift-File. I don´t get it working.. But thanks for your help :)

Comment: Great Medium story.. but I dont get it to work for me :( i think the problem is that i work with SwiftUI and not UIKit and ViewController / Playgrounds.

Comment: Have you implemented `coordinator`?

Comment: I dont think so, but I´m new in Swift / AR Development.. i think I need more experience. In the first Post is the complete Code. If I try to implemented the [Coordinator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582392/swiftui-passing-data-from-swiftuiview-to-scenekit/60590065#60590065) i get errors..